# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String android studio settext

Tags: android, android-studio, classcastexception

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

ERROR LINE

```
String data = (String) dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue();
```

---

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String userUid = user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       ERROR LINE     String data = (String) dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue();
            moneyText.setText(data);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error line, you are trying to cast one object into another which is not supported. The correct way of doing this is to use the `valueOf` method within the String class like so:

```
String data = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this way

```
String data = ((Long) dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue()).toString();
```

Your data is Long and you are casting in to String

Answer (score 0):

Long to String Example:

```
long testL ong = 10;
String stringLoc = Long.toString(testLong );
System.out.println("str : " + stringLoc );
```

In your code trying to cast Long to String. You can try below code.

```
 String data = Long.toString(dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue()`
 is Long type and you directly casting to string you can use like below to avoid error.

```
String data = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("money").getValue());
```